# error message when sudo apt update

Tags: apt, updates

When I type 'sudo apt update' error message comes out every time, since I installed whale browser. What's matter and what is a greate solution? Just ignore it?

Edit : I'm using ubuntu 20.04 and the error message is omitted. Error message :

```
Failed to fetch https://repo.whale.naver.com/stable/deb/dists/stable/InRelease  Could not connect to repo.whale.naver.com:443 (125.209.218.142). - connect (111: Connection refused)
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

This is the source file.

```
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ### 
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb [arch=amd64] https://repo.whale.naver.com/stable/deb stable main
```

Comment: Please add the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/naver*`

Comment: @Someone ### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb [arch=amd64] https://repo.whale.naver.com/stable/deb/ stable main
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb [arch=amd64] https://repo.whale.naver.com/stable/deb/ stable main

Comment: @Someone I don't know why terminal saying repeatedly, this is the output

Comment: @Chiyoung Please edit your question and post the output there. Also to format this, highlight the code and then press CTRL+K before you click save.

Comment: @ArturMeinild I realized they actually were using https because the error says https. I tried https in my sources list file for that repo and got the same error. It works fine with http in the sources.list file.

Comment: @Chiyoung Your answer is below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using https and the site requires http. Apt normally doesn't use https and uses a different method of security by signing the packages.

Run the following command to fix the problem (edit the file using `sed`):

```
sudo sed -i 's|https://repo.whale|http://repo.whale|g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/naver-whale.list
```

Then run apt update:

```
sudo apt update
```

and don't forget to upgrade:

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

or

```
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

to include kernel updates.

Comment: Thank you, your solution is fit to my problem. But I wonder what is going on when I enter sudo sed-i 's|~, I searched for it but I can't find command parameter with 's|'. So can you tell me what is going on and from where did you edit https to http?

Comment: @Chiyoung Normally, we use `sed 's/foo/bar/g` to replace `foo` with `bar`. However, here we want to replace something that contains a forward-slash `/`. We could escape all forward slashes or we could use `|` instead of `/` with the sed command to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Chiyoung Basically, we don't have to use forward slashes with `sed` we can use pipes `|` and we can also use other characters like comments `#` in place of forward slashes. So,  `s/foo/bar/g` and  `s|foo|bar|g` and `s#foo#bar#g` and even `s$foo$bar$g` will all work the same. This is a handy trick when your text contains special characters.

Comment: @Chiyoung `'s|https://repo.whale|http://repo.whale|g'` is the same as `'s/https:\/\/repo.whale/http:\/\/repo.whale/g'`

Comment: @Chiyoung To be more precise, the first character after `s` is used as a separator. So we can even use the letter `p` like this: `'spfoopbarpg'` instead of `'s/foo/bar/g'`